# Error enviando xml firmado al ws de DGI

Tags: vb.net, webservice

La DGI de Uruguay está implementado la factura electrónica.
Yo usando VS 2010 ya firmé el xml y probé enviarlo vía SoapUi. Anda bien.
Cuando intento enviarlo desde mi programa (en C# o vb.net, aplicación de windows form), habiendo creado la referencia de servicio a (https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6443/ePrueba/ws_eprueba?wsdl)) sólo me contesta "Error al consumir Servicio Web".

**Mi código es**

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim WS As New Servicio4.WS_eFacturaSoapPortClient

    Dim ClaveDelCertificado As String = "Prueba.01"
    Dim certPath As String
    certPath = Path.Combine("G:\A-enviar\", "PKPrueba - EMPRESA.pfx")

    Dim Certi As New X509Certificate2(certPath, ClaveDelCertificado, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable Or X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet)

    WS.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Certi
    Dim xEnviar As New WS_Enviar4.Servicio4.Data()
    Dim xRecib As New WS_Enviar4.Servicio4.Data()
    *Dim Sobre_cCFE As String = "G:\A-enviar\Sobre17_09_13T20_52_31.xml"*
    *Dim campo() As String*
    *campo = File.ReadAllLines(Sobre_cCFE)*
    *xEnviar.xmlData = campo.ToString*
    Try
        xRecib = WS.EFACRECEPCIONSOBRE(xEnviar)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

y **mi app.config**

```vb
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WS_eFacturaSoapBinding">
              <security mode="Transport" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="WS_eFacturaSoapBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6443/ePrueba/ws_eprueba"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS_eFacturaSoapBinding"
          contract="Servicio4.WS_eFacturaSoapPort" name="WS_eFacturaSoapPort" >
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Por favor, ayúdenme, estoy trancado con esto. Supongo que en algún lado debería informar al WS cual es .pfx y su clave para autenticar; no sé donde hacerlo. Y lo otro, está bien cargada la factura firmada para envío?

```vb
Dim Sobre_cCFE As String = "G:\A-enviar\Sobre17_09_13T20_52_31.xml"
Dim campo() As String
campo = File.ReadAllLines(Sobre_cCFE)
xEnviar.xmlData = campo.ToString
```

El contenido que debería tener la variable xEnviar.xmldata cuando lo intento adjuntar me lo trunca y lo deforma: hay alguna forma de adjuntarlo?

Comment: Verifica que tú certificado sea válido. Que no esté caducado y que el sistema DGI lo acepte.

Comment: También muestra el contenido completo de la excepción. Su InnerException y su StackTrace para verificar

Comment: Puedes mostrar también el contenido de xEnviar.xmlData? Para ver si está firmado.

Comment: El código es obviamente VB.Net, no C#. He editado tu pregunta

Comment: Es así Pikoh, el código que expuse es VB.NET. Lo que traté de decir es que lo he hecho tanto en VB.NET como en C#, perdón si no fuí claro. Gracias por interesarte, si tienes alguna sugerencia sobre mi problema, por favor!
Saluduos
   Chiquito

Comment: Gracias Sergio por tu respuesta. Lo que hice fué enviar el xml que figura en el código vía SoapUi y DGI lo aceptó como bueno. Por tanto el certificado es 100% válido y el xml está bien firmado. El contenido de la variable xEnviar.xmlData, haciendo una "Inspección rápida" de tipo texto es System.String[] En cuanto a la InnerException vi que es Nothing. La Stack Trace no sé como obtenerla.
Por favor, que está mal?
 Gracias Chiquito

Comment: Ruben, perdón la molestia, estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo para DGI uruguay y estoy teniendo problemas para firmar el XML, me podrás dar una mano con eso ? Mil gracias